# Selenium, Python 3, simple scraping text from Erowid LSD experiences?

Tags: html, xpath, web-scraping

Based off of an answer on here about a similar thing, I tried to scrape the text of Erowid trip experiences. The URL has a bunch of trip links. I want to click each link and then print the `'report-text-surround'` element, which is the trip text.

```
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.erowid.org/experiences/exp.cgi?S1=2&S2=-3&C1=9&Str=')

#I tried to get hrefs by xpath, knowing that each trip links starts with 'exp.php?ID'.

view_links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[contains(text(), 'exp.php?ID')]""")
for index, view in enumerate(view_links):
    html = view.get_attribute('innerHTML')
    href = html.split('"')[1]

    view_links[index] = href

#And then visit each href and get the data
for href in view_links:
    driver.get(href)

    #I know this is the element containing the trip text. 
    trip_text = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('report-text-surround')
    for trip in trip_text:
        print (trip.text.encode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 0):

So you are pretty close but there are just 2 small mistakes.

```
trip_text = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('report-text-surround')
for trip in trip_text:
    print (trip.text.encode('utf-8'))
```

Your `driver.find_elements_by_class_name` should not be plural, as there is only one on the page.  It has a lot of elements, but only one class ('report-text-surround').  This means you're going to get all the text at once, you could change this but you'd have to go through the child elements or get the elements seperately.

You can change that entire section to this:

```
text = (driver.find_element_by_class_name('report-text-surround').text).encode('utf-8')

print(text);
```

That will give you all of the text in the entire article. An easy way to split this up after would be to split each part of the text by \n\n.